# handle one to many relationship in thymeleaf using spring mvc

Tags: spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm having One entity as Vendor and Another as Address and the relationship between both of them is One To Many form Vendor to Address.

Note : I am using JPA

My Vendor Entity

```
public class Vendor {

 private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private List<Address> address;

 // getter and setters

}
```

Address class:

```
public class Address {

private Integer id;

private String addressline1;
private String addressline2;

//getter and setters 
}
```

Now I am using Thymeleaf , I have a scenario where I need to add the address dynamically to a form for the particular vendor.

How do I do Object binding for the Address object in Vendor using Thymeleaf in spring mvc?

Comment: What do you mean by "add the address dynamically"?

Comment: I will be hacking one button where onclick event will create a form having address attribute with will again need to bind with the vendor object list of address

Answer (score 0):

Comment if i didn't understand your question correct, it's a bit unclear to me...

In order to access the address(s) of a vendor, you provide a vendor within your controller (something like `model.addAttribute("vendor", currentVendor);`) and call vendor.address in your html file. Please note that this will give you a list so you need to iterate to show all address:

```
<tr th:each="address : ${vendor.address}">
    <td th:text="${address.id}">1</td>
    <td th:text="${address.addressline1}"></td>
    <td th:text="${address.addressline2}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In this manner i am actually showing the details of address on html page , but i ask is to set the data from the form to my model using thymeleaf
@viergelenkar

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh, that's tricky because binding to form doesn't work in a dynamic way. That means you can't do something like @Viergelenker suggests **AND** bind each address-object to his own form.

You can add a single address object to the model, e.g.

```
model.addAttribute("address", addressObject); // Snippet for Model-object
modelAndView.addObject("address", addressObject); // Snippet for ModelAndView object
```

and then define a form in yout template like:

```
<form .... method=".." th:object="${address}">
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" >
  <input type="text" th:field="*{addressline1}" >
  <input type="text" th:field="*{addressline2}" >
</form>
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to add a array or list to the model and bind each object in that collection to his own form:

```
/* The following code doesn't work */
<th:block th:each="address : ${addresses}">
    <form .... method=".." th:object="${address}">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{addressline1}" >
      ...
    </form>
</th:block>
```

or

```
/* The following code doesn't work */
<th:block th:each="address, stat : ${addresses}">
    <form .... method=".." th:object="${addresses[__stat.index__]}">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{addressline1}" >
      ...
    </form>
</th:block>
```

What you can do is not to use form binding and just send some name-value pairs from forms without the binding (just use the name and the th:value attributes and not the th:field attribute in your forms) to the controller, get them there from the HttpServletRequest object and create/update/delete address-objects ... or bind the whole Vendor object to a form (note the use of stat.index):

```
<form th:object="${vendor}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{name}"> // feel free to make that field editable
    <th:block th:each="addr, stat : *{address}">
      <input type="hidden" th:field="*{address[__${stat.index}__].id}">         
      <input type="text" th:field="*{address[__${stat.index}__].addressline1}">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{address[__${stat.index}__].addressline2}">
    </th:block>
 </form>
```

Comment: If you have a look at the last code-snippet: Modify a address entry is simple. It's possible to add or delete a address from the vendor object, too ... but again it's tricky.